# Using Twitter Bootstrap on my blog. How can I get the side bar to collapse for mobile devices?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here's a page from my site.

http://jddorweiler.appspot.com/roomba.html

The side bar looks fine from a computer but from a mobile device it blocks most of the screen and covers most of the content. Is there an easy way I can get it to collapse into the top bar or another way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .sidebar-nav-fixed {
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bootstrap's responsive CSS, you can give your current sidebar the class `.hidden-phone` and create a collapsed version with the classes `.hidden-tablet` and `.hidden-desktop`.

[Scaffolding • Bootstrap (Responsive utility classes)](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)